# How can I calculate initial X and Y velocity given the starting coordinates, target coordinates, friction and duration? (No gravity)

Tags: html-canvas, projectile-physics

I am really new to mixing physics and game development, and I would like to find the initial velocity required to launch the gray dot from point A to point B, given a time. I’ve tried many tutorials and answers given by other people, but lots of them take gravity into account, even though my scenario doesn’t have gravity.

```js
class Player {

// ...

    update() {
        this.draw();
        this.velocity.multiply(this.friction);
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
    }

    launch(point, time) {
        let vel = new Vector();
        vel.x = (point.position.x - this.position.x) / time;
        vel.y = (point.position.y - this.position.y) / time;
        this.velocity = vel;
    }

// ...

}
```

[image]